# Iphone 5 suddenly stopped connecting to network

Tags: iphone, network, wifi

I was sitting at work when my iphone 5 showed that it was not connected to the network anymore. I went into my settings, clicked on the network I wanted and it told me I was unable to join the network. I then tried to forget the network and try to reconnect but the same thing "unable to join network". I then went a step further and reset my network settings under general settings. Now I am not only unable to connect to the network but it is also now asking for a username. It has never asked for a username before.

I have reset the router 3 times, reset my phone several times and still same issue. I have watched every YouTube video, talked to apple support via chat and non of them seem to work. I have tried messing with WPA and WPA2 settings, etc... I know its not a problem with the connection because coworkers are able to connect with no problem. They are not being asked for a username when logging on. I am lost at this point what to do. I dont want to do a factory reset but may have to at this point.Trying this before I do so. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

1. Put your iPhone in AirPlane Mode
2. Go to Settings > General > Reset
3. Reset Network Settings
4. Reboot your Router
5. Take you iPhone out of AirPlane mode..

You will be prompted to join your network again, and it should work this time...

Comment: I put my iPhone in Airplane Mode, I reset my network settings, I rebooted the router, my phone in the mean time restarted, but when it came back up it was no longer in airplane mode and the same issue is there. It is asking for Username and Password. (There is no username)

Comment: @SimonCrapo Try this : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114907/iphone-5-always-asks-for-username-when-connect-to-wifi

Comment: Also try this : Go to `Settings > Privacy > Location Services > System Services` then turn off `Wi-Fi Networking`. Restart your iPhone, turn on `Wi-Fi Networking` and check again.